# What is the life story and miracles associated with Sri ShyAmAcharan lAhiri (mahAshaya)?

Tags: guru, life, yogi, kriyayoga

Sri lahiri mahashaya was a well known yogi who lived in Varanasi. He was a householder yogi.

His contribution was immense in propagating yoga.

What is his life story?

What are the books written by him ?

What are the miracles associated with him?